# Spring MVC behind reverse proxy (Zuul)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul

I'm building an application is based on the Microservices architecture. I have a microservice that uses Spring MVC and a reverse proxy is provided by Zuul. 
Without Zuul my microservice is accessed by 
`http://localhost/` and with proxy by `http://localhost/ui/` . 
So when I click on a link on the main page I have to go `http://localhost/ui/order` but I go to `http://localhost/order` and of course I get "Not found".
When a request goes throw Zuul, Zuul adds the headers: `X-Forwarded-Host`, `X-Forwarded-Port`, `X-Forwarded-Prefix` (equals /ui/).

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.2 + Thymeleaf + Tomcat.

Question: How can I configure spring mvc to add prefix to my links or maybe exist another solution?

**UPD:** I found an interesting behavior.
I replaced the link from {/order} to {./order} and when I'm on `http://localhost` the link has a next href `http://localhost/order` , but when I'm on `http://localhost/` (add /) the link has `http://localhost/ui/order` . What is this?

Comment: have you configure your spring boot app to accept CORS requests?

Comment: Yes. I allowed all origins, all headers and etc.

Comment: as to your update: that's simply a relative path (starting with "./") this isnt that surprising. the other issue ... i am having the same. thymeleaf does not consider the "x-forwarded-prefix" header ... :/